# "Where have you been" vs "Where have you gone"

Tags: present-perfect, been-vs-gone

Is it possible at all to use the sentence "where have you gone" in a situation in which your friend has **just** come back home.

For example:

> A. Sorry, I am late.
>
> B. Where  have you   gone or gone to or been or been to
>
> A. To the shop

Comment: It's not appropriate to use “Where have you gone?” since it implies that the person that went to the shop hasn't returned yet. You would normally ask “Where did you go?” or “Where have you been?”

Comment: Does this answer your question? [They have been to Washington (they are there now vs. they are back now)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14271/they-have-been-to-washington-they-are-there-now-vs-they-are-back-now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where have you gone?

This implies that you are still there. Somebody might ask this on the phone, but not face to face.

> Where have you been?

This implies that you were somewhere else, but you are here now. Somebody would say this face to face.