# to vs. in (Present perfect)

Tags: prepositions

I've just started to explore details about tenses. And one point doesn't take me a clear understanding. Maybe this is not about tenses at all.

So.
There is a few examples, and I don't really get, why first is using "in", and other using "to".

```
1 (In)
Have you always lived in Chicago?
How long has your sister been in Australia?

2 (To)
Have you been to California?
They've been to Japan.
```

I've thought it's about a scale of place or something, but it's not(Japan is a country but using with "to").
Maybe it's about accent on time(1)/place(2)?

Comment: Also related [They have been to Washington (they are there now vs. they are back now)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14271/they-have-been-to-washington-they-are-there-now-vs-they-are-back-now) From our sister-site, EL&U: [Difference between "been to" and "been in"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77603/difference-between-been-to-and-been-in)

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Yes! Thank you so much!

Comment: For "live in", you can generally use "in" for any sort of place name. The size does it matter; whether it's a city, a country, a continent, does not matter either -- I live in California - I live in Canada - I live in North America - I live in Japan - I live in Europe, etc.

Comment: The only time it wouldn't work seems to me is if you're talking about living on a boat, on an ocean, on a planet, on a space station, etc. then we would use *on* rather than in. For example: I live on (the) Earth. Some astronauts live on the ISS. Some day, I wonder if it would be possible to live on Mars.

Comment: Also if you live on a particular named mountain, *on* is probably most appropriate. If the name refers to a range of mountains, *in* would be appropriate. E.g. She lives *in* the Rockies.  He lives *on* Mt Fuji.